# GridViewCheckBoxColumn gerando uma coluna em branco

Tags: c#, gridview, visual-studio-2010, telerik

Estou criando um formulário do tipo **RadControls Winforms Application**  para para realizar um simples cadastro de pessoas .

Neste formulário estou utilizando o **Telerik Rad Controls**

Para utilizar o **checkbox** para cada item da lista utilizei o  [GridViewCheckBoxColumn](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-columns-gridviewcheckboxcolumn.html)

Este o meu código para o carregamento da **Grid**

```
 private void Carrega_Lista()
        {
            GridPessoas.DataSource = Negocio.Pessoa.ConsultarPessoa();
            GridPessoas.EnableFiltering = true;
            GridPessoas.MasterTemplate.ShowFilteringRow = true;
            GridPessoas.AddSelectCheckBoxColumn();
        }
```

Porem ao adicionar o `GridPessoas.AddSelectCheckBoxColumn();`

Esta sendo gerado uma coluna em branco , veja na figura abaixo :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como posso solucionar isso ?

Comment: O Que retorna o seu DS? Negocio.Pessoa.ConsultarPessoa(); Como está o controle HTML?

Comment: Perdão , esqueci de mencionar estou usando o RadControls Winforms Application e uma aplicação desktop e não web , irei editar a pergunta .

Comment: De qualquer modo, tenta aumentar a LARGURA desta coluna e ve se nao tem controles dentro dela

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Consegui resolver obrigado pela sua atenção =D

Comment: O que você fez?

Comment: Postei a resposta da uma olhada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resolução do problema e muito simples basta você inserir o comando no **construtor**  e não no `Carrega_Lista();`

```
public Principal()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  GridPessoas.AddSelectCheckBoxColumn();
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]